# How can I use a torrent to copy large files across a flakey network connection

Tags: networking, bittorrent, p2p

I'm migrating some huge virtual machine files from developer laptops onto a central virtual host, but the connection between our office and the data centre is somewhat unreliable.

It looks like a typical copy is going to be >15 hours and I wouldn't bet my lunch money that it wouldn't drop out in that time. How can I set up uTorrent or even Opera to do the copy in chunks so I can confidently let it run unattended?

Comment: I recommend [BitTorrent Sync](http://labs.bittorrent.com/experiments/sync.html). It's portable and very easy to use. And it doesn't require the creation of .torrent files. I successfully used it to copy >100GiB over flaky wireless connections. Another option is `rsync`, which is very robust and fast.

Comment: Yes it will work with utorrent: File --> Create New Torrent --> Click Add File. Pretty much self-explanatory. Other valid ways would be to use Skype since it reports resuming and can dig even through company firewalls. Also, you could FTP it using FileZilla which is a free FTP client and server program.

Comment: @Zerobinary99 Skype is the worst of all possibilities. It is an unstable piece of software and it is *very very very* slow. It is not even remotely capable of maxing out a decent network connection. Bittorrents (Sync or traditional .torrents) easily go up to 40-60 MiB/s, rsync runs at the same speed here, but skype transfers consistenly stay below 0.5 MiB/s. Furthermore it requires a GUI and is totally unsuitable for data transfers.

Comment: @Marco Agreed. Except: Speed is way faster than what you make it out to be. I'm transferring files through it with 1MBit and that's my max upstream. I also received files with several MBit/s from faster connections. If you had those experiences then your Skype was probably behind a well secured firewall. I also merely suggested it since the author of the question apparently fails at even setting up a torrent with the dead easy to use utorrent and sometimes a less efficient solution is better than one that goes beyond the capabilities of the person seeking help. Also, a Gui isn't a bad thing...

Comment: @Zerobinary99 Assuming you mean 1MBit/s, that's 122KiB/s and way less than the 500KiB/s I mentioned. I'd be surprised if someone can confirm that a file transfer over skype goes up to several MiB/s, let alone 50MiB/s.

Answer (score 1):

I took @Marco's advice and tried BitTorrent Sync and can report back that I have been using it for a couple of weeks and have found it reliable and simple to use.